# How to access query parameters in vapor 3

Tags: swift, rest, query-string, vapor

Basically the title. I want to know how to use url query parameters in **Vapor 3**. I can't seem to find anything in the docs on it.

e.g. `/objects?fancy=true`, how do I access the `fancy` parameter.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can do something like e.g.:

```
guard let fancy = req.query[Bool.self, at: "fancy"] else {
    throw Abort(.badRequest)
}
```

Or if it's optional you could do

```
if let qFancy = try? req.query.get(Bool.self, at: "fancy") {
    fancy = qFancy
} else {
    fancy = false
}
```

Comment: Hi! What if GET param is optional, sometimes sent sometimes not? How can I check existence?